# Setting UIToolbar background image with iOS5.1

Tags: iphone, background-image, uitoolbar, ios5.1

I used the following code to set the image "Sample" as a background color of my UIToolbar

```
self.toolbar.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sample.png"].CGImage;
```

But it seems the above one does not works with iOS5.1 and the default background color of UIToolbar appeared. I doesn't have any problem with this line in iOS4.

Am I missing something? Please suggest me the reason..

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
// Create resizable images
UIImage *gradientImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"] 
                            resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
// Set the background image for *all* UINavigationBars
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44 
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Better to use appearance API introduced with iOS 5. May this will help you

Comment: Thanks! Just a note that this must be done in a view controller somewhere, I was trying it in the app delegate and it wasn't working for a while...

Comment: Any suggestions how to do this in AppDelegate to create different toolbar backgrounds for different screens?..

Comment: See my solution for a correct way to do this, that also works from the app delegate.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way, which works from the app delegate (unlike the solution above) and which is also marked with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR in the header files, is:

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:bgImage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:bgImage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

Answer (score 1):

[setBackgroundImage:forToolbarPosition:barMetrics:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIToolbar/setBackgroundImage%3aforToolbarPosition%3abarMetrics%3a) this is used to set the image to use for the background in a given position and with given metrics.,

In your case

```
// Set the background image for PortraitMode
[self.toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sample.png"] 
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
// and For LandscapeMode
[self.toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sample.png"] 
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```