# iOS: UIToolbar setBackgroundImage not working

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

I can not change the uitoolbar background image. gives error.

This navigationBar code is working.

```
UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bartop.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But this toolbar code is not working and gives error.

```
UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bartop.png"];
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Where is my wrong?

---

UPDATE:

This code is working:

```
UIImage *testimage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bartop"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:testimage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:testimage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

Comment: you should not add image extension .png, as for it 2x will be ignored.

Comment: It did not work, I still get the error.

Comment: That wasn't answer to this, That was just an info :p

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting UIToolbar background image with iOS5.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332040/setting-uitoolbar-background-image-with-ios5-1)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya i always use the extension with `UIImage` and the @2x works just fine.

Comment: @KDaker: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595365/jpg-images-in-iphone-and-2x-images

Comment: @AnoopVaidya this link working to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332040/setting-uitoolbar-background-image-with-ios5-1 Thank you.

Comment: That is what i marked as dupe for this

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation, the method you need to use with UIToolbar is

```
- setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forToolbarPosition:(UIToolbarPosition)topOrBottom barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

You are using

```
- setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

Try using that and see if it works for you.

[More info here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006927-CH3-SW4).